# Django 1.5 html issue, href does not appear

Tags: html, django

Hi i'm having some problems with Django 1.5. I'm writing a simple template but i can't display an link (href tag) into my page.
this is my code

```
{% extends "forum_base.html" %}
{% load uni_form_tags %}

{% block title %}Lista dei Forums{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h3><a href="{% url "image_index" %}"></a></h3> >> <h3><a href="{% url "forum_index" %}"></a></h3>
{% for forum in forums %}
<h3><a href="{% url "forum_thread_list" forum_id=forum.pk %}">{{ forum.title }}</a></h3>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

i cannot display this line :

```
    <h3><a href="{% url "image_index" %}"></a></h3> >> <h3><a href="{% url "forum_index" %}"></a></h3>
```

Can someone explain me where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a html issue.

`<h3><a href="{% url "image_index" %}">YOURTEXTHERE</a></h3> >> <h3><a href="{% url "forum_index" %}">YOURTEXTHERE</a></h3>`